# jQuery Promise timing

Tags: jquery, promise

I have a page where I need to load data from the database via AJAX and I need to load elements onto the page. Now the elements only need to be loaded onto the page once, but the data needs to be loaded many times. Then I have a process that puts the data into the elements.

I've called the promise that resolves when the elements are loaded `elementsPromise` in the code below.

My question is about how to make and remake a promise that resolves each time the data is loaded. I have a plan, but given the vagaries of timing I'm unsure whether my test ([jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/g49je7j6/1/)), is reliable. Hence the question, which amounts to "should the approach work?":

I make a function that returns a promise and a variable created from it each time. e.g.

```
function getData() {
    def = new $.Deferred;
    // more code
    return def.promise();
}

dataPromise = getData();
```

Then I have code after the above:

```
$.when(dataPromise, elementsPromise).done(function () {
    putDataInElements();
});
```

My fear is that the second or later times `putDataInElements()` could run straight away, because the `$.when` won't wait for `dataPromise` to be redefined, it will instead read the prior state before the function has returned a new promise.

Please help, as promise use has been troubling me for a while now and, while I think that my approach will work, any further insight I can get into how promises work would be greatly appreciated.

PS. Even if my approach is fine I'd appreciate it if someone could please explain exactly why it's fine.

Thanks.

Comment: About promises, you may want to read this very good post here: http://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html. It may help you and teach you stuffs like do not use defer.

Comment: Though apparently jQuery doesn't let you much choice about the use of defer :-(

Comment: If dataPromise is redefined before the $.when call is made again it will work. It all depends on the sequence.

Comment: I think it's starting to make sense to me now. What I'd forgotten is that javascript is only asynchronous where it's explicitly asynchronous, in this case the AJAX call in the function. So unless I'm much mistaken the function resolves, redefining the promise, before the $.when is called, so long as it runs before it. If I also make sure that the function only resolves the promise (either in the callback or the AJAX's .done/.then) when the AJAX has completed it should be okay.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with a slightly different approach since this is a good place to show the power of MVC for separating and managing your views and models (data), bound by a single controller.

#### Introduction, i.e goals

Our goal is to generate a static UI that will be generated once, but Updated multiple times.

#### Technologies

We will use jQuery

#### Implementation

We will assume our application is made out of 3 main parts:

- Model - the data
- View - the HTML/DOM
- Controller - something to merge and manage the two

the rest will be made out of services which, for our example, will be the methods provided by jQuery, which from here on will be referred to as JQ.

#### bootstrap code

```
//controller
function Ctrl() {
   this.viewRendered = false;
}

Ctrl.prototype.init = function() {
  // magic happens here

  // $http is a promise
  var data = $http.get("http://my-data-endpoint.com/params");

  // when we get something back
  // 'data' is your model
  $.when(data, function(data) {

    // cache the jQuery container to prevent repetitive search
    // it's also your view, get to know each other - it'll be worth your while
    var $container = $("#dataContainer");

    //if the view was already rendered, let's fill it with the new data
    if(this.viewRendered) {
       var $items = $container.find("li");
       $items.each(function(i, el) { //notice the inverted $.each syntax
         $(el).text(data[i]); //we put in the data, according to its placement, assuming it's symmetric
       });
    } else {
    //if the view havn't been rendered yet - let's create it via the data
    data.forEach(function(el) {
      $container.append("<li>" + el.text + "</li>");
    });
    this.viewRendered = true;
  }
  }.bind(this));
}

var ctrl = new Ctrl();
ctrl.init();
```

#### HTML

```
<ul id="dataContainer"></ul>
```

#### Explanation

As promises are singletons by nature, such collision, suggested by you, won't happen.

However, you don't need to use deferred objects, as jQuerys native $http service and its derivatives are deferred as well, so just pass those calls directly into your $.when statement:

```
var def = $.get("http://your-data-endpoint.com/whatevs");

$.when(def).done(function(data) {
  ...
});
```

Our main goal is to create a 3 part entity, which has 2 parts: a view and a model, which is the data that should be represented within the view.

We then create a controller with a flag, allowing us to know whether the view was already invoked or not and choose the proper rendering method:

- Creating the view by the provided data
- Applying the data into the rendered view.

You can abstract it even further, and separate the logic from your controller, i.e - allow your view to automatically render the provided data according to a predefined template, in the same manner angularJS or react manage their views, but i thought it was an overkill.

Hope it was clear enough.